Why the class variable of Super Class is not incremented?
I created a Vehicle super class and MyCar,MyTruck sub classes. There is @@number_of_vehicles class variables that keeps track of number of Instances instantiated from the Sub Classes.

And a class method that prints that class variable

But it prints 0 even after creating objects from the sub classes.
class Vehicle
  @@number_of_vehicles = 0

  def self.number_of_vehicles
    puts "This program has created #{@@number_of_vehicles} vehicles"
  end

  def self.gas_mileage(gallons, miles)
    puts "#{miles / gallons} miles per gallon of gas"
  end

  def initialize
    @@number_of_vehicles += 1
  end
end

class MyCar < Vehicle
  NUMBER_OF_DOORS = 4
  #code omitted for brevity...
end

class MyTruck < Vehicle
  NUMBER_OF_DOORS = 2
end


"code omitted for brevity..." – the omitted code is what's causing the problem ;)

Please, post text as text, not as pictures of text. This is a website for programmers, not painters. We want to copy&paste&run your code, copy&paste your inputs, read your outputs, and copy&paste&google your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective. Also, please make sure to post everything relevant to answering your question in your question, not behind a link. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2988 https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

You'd be well-advised to avoid class variables.

You need to add super call to initialize methods in your MyCar and MyTruck classes:
class MyCar < Vehicle
  NUMBER_OF_DOORS = 4

  def initialize
    super
    puts "MyCar initialized"
  end
end

Without it the initialize method in Vehicle class is not called.
